# What version of Ruby is required for P4Ruby and where is P4Ruby installed?

Tags: ruby, windows, perforce

I am trying to set up Ruby and P4Ruby so I can use the [p4replicate.rb script](http://public.perforce.com/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/utils/p4replicate/p4replicate.html), but whenever I run the p4ruby18.exe (from [the Perforce FTP](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/bin.ntx86/)) I get the following error:

> **Perforce P4Ruby API for Ruby 1.8 - InstallShield Wizard**
>
> There was a problem tying to get the P4Ruby install path.
>
> Possible reasons are:
>
> 1) Ruby is not installed.
>
> 2) An unsupported version of Ruby is installed.
>
> 3) The folder containing the Ruby executable is not in the system path.
>
> 4) The folder of another version's executable is in the system path before the supported version.
>
> 5) The P4Ruby install paths are not writable.
>
> *OK*

I'm running Windows Vista, and have Ruby 1.8.6-p398 installed in C:\Ruby186.  The directory C:\Ruby186\bin is the first thing on my Path variable (the Ruby installer put it there)!  I've also confirmed it's accessible by running `which ruby` (cygwin is installed) which returns `/cygdrive/c/Ruby186/bin/ruby`.  I've tried 1.8.7-p334 and 1.9.2-p290 as well.

The [P4Ruby release notes](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/doc/user/p4rubynotes.txt) claim that Ruby 1.8 is supported for versions of P4Ruby 2007.3 onwards, so I thought I'd met this criteria but it will not install.

As I'm fairly certainly I've met criteria 1, 3 and 4, I wondered whether anyone could tell me if they've managed to install P4Ruby on Windows with a specific version of Ruby (2), and if so what path P4Ruby installs to (5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a sanity check: do you have admin rights when running the installer?

Comment: That is a good sanity check to make!  I'm away from that PC right now.  I'll check tomorrow and report back.  Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, you were right @p4-randall I needed to right-click and `Run as administrator`.  Why does Windows do this to me? :-(

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own specific questions (rather than solve my problem as thankfully @p4-randall did):

1. the p4rubynotes.txt manual says *"The P4Ruby Windows installer requires Ruby 1.8."*
2. P4Ruby is seemingly not installed anywhere!  To clarify this, it looks like the P4 client is updated with a version supporting P4Ruby, so the directory it needs to write to is the Perforce installation directory (e.g. `C:\program Files\Perforce\`).